# PhpStorm Path not found inspection

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

```
require_once APP . DS . 'controllers' . DS . $this->controller . '.php';
```

I'm including controller. It has default value set and it always has to find something. In real world it works, but this inspection is still shinning in my IDE and I would like to solve it somehow.

Inspection says this

```
Path '/media/matej/space/www/rs/app/controllers/$this->controller' not found
```

How can I explain it, that I am aware of what is happening? Is there some comment to solve this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using very dynamic code here .. which cannot be evaluated properly in IDE using static analysis alone (as you are using `$this->controller` which can be anything during run time).

Two options here:

1. Suppress warning for this line only -- just place `/** @noinspection PhpIncludeInspection */` on a line before that.

   This option makes sense only if you have very little of such suppressions in your code, otherwise half of the file will be suppression comments :)
2. Just turn off such inspection completely -- adding such suppression comments all the time (often) looks ugly and not a desired way in general.

   For that: `Settings | Editor | Inspections | PHP | General --> Unresolved include`. It could be done for whole project or for some custom scope only.

Comment: 2nd one help me with the newest update of php strome. But anyway its not recommended to hide issues.